# Key generation of an application in WSO2 API Maneger

Tags: wso2-identity-server

In API manager inside store we can create consumer key and consumer secret using generate keys button for an application.I am just digging the java code where its getting generated so that i can try to generate keys using a **different identity server** not API Manager's default identity server.

I am trying the same in **wso2am-2.2.0-update7** version.

Main motive is using the **third party identity server** for keys and token generation.

Answer (score 0):

Please refer https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM220/Configuring+a+Third-Party+Key+Manager. This contains what you need to do to configure third party IDP as a Key Manager in APIM